# MySQL show a row that appears more than once with different values?

Tags: mysql, count

For a table (Ingredients) like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|id   |fruit|
+-----+-----+
|  1  | or  |
|  1  | ban |
|  2  | or  |
|  2  | or  |
+-----+-----+
```

I want to have a query that should produce a result like this:

> id **1** is associated with two types of fruits.

I do not care if multiple rows have the same data, I only care if rows with the same id have different fruits.

> e.g. id 2 is only associated with one type of fruit in both rows, i do not care about that!!!

I have pseudo code for what I want to achieve but not any mysql

```
Select all id's
From the ingredients table
Group by id
If group count of id is greater than 1 and has different fruits then display
```

I have a funny feeling I might not be able to do this in Mysql and will have to use some PHP.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Uh, I think you need to spend some time on learning what an id should be. Hint: If you have more than one row with the same ID, you're (almost certainly) doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks but the example does not really show what I am doing and due to the way the system works 3NF is not the best for it!

Comment: Well then post your schema. We're not mindreaders.

Comment: If `id` means `salad_id` or somethign similar and there are other columns too, I wouldn't assume it's not in 3NF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pseudo code in SQL:

```
SELECT id
FROM ingredients
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT fruit ) > 1
```

and if it's slow, you can try this version - `MAX()` and `MIN()` may be faster than `COUNT(DISTINCT )` - although it's less readable:

```
SELECT id
FROM ingredients
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX( fruit ) > MIN( fruit )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the query is fine for my dataset.


Much appreciated @ypercube !

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) > 1
```